# Parse complex matching delimiters

Tags: python, html, pyparsing

Structures like HTML-Tags have an opening and a closing part, sharing an identical tag to match them to each other.

```html
<tag> ... </tag>
```

I want to capture these pairs and their content using the `pyparsing` library. I know how to specify a single tag.

```py
from pyparsing import SkipTo, makeHTMLTags
open, close = makeHTMLTags("tag")
(open + SkipTo(close) + close).parseString("<tag> Tag content </tag>")
# yields ['tag', False, 'Tag content ', '</tag>']
```

I am also aware that, when specifying multiple distinct tags, each of them needs a dedicated rule to avoid that one tag closes another. So when the set of tags is `Or(("tag", "other"))` simply extending the former example

```py
from pyparsing import SkipTo, makeHTMLTags, Or
open, close = makeHTMLTags(Or(("tag", "other")))
(open + SkipTo(close) + close).parseString("<other><tag> Tag content </tag></other>")
# yields ['other', False, '<tag> Tag content ', '</tag>']
```

yields mismatched tags. The parser closes the opening `<other>` with `</tag>`. This can be amended by specifying dedicated rules for each tag.

```py
from pyparsing import SkipTo, makeHTMLTags, Or
Or((
  open + SkipTo(close) + close
  for open, close in
  map(makeHTMLTags, ("tag", "other"))
)).parseString("<other><tag> Tag content </tag></other>")
# yields ['other', False, '<tag> Tag content </tag>', '</other>']
```

Now I would, for example, like to find all tags starting with `t`, thus searching for `Word('t', alphas)` instead of `Or(("tag", "other", ...))`. How can I make tags match when the set of tags to match is possibly infinite?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pyparsing module, but your problem seems can be solved by [lxml(Library for processing XML and HTML in Python)](http://lxml.de/). Following is my example code using lxml:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree


def pprint(l):
    for i, tag in enumerate(l):
        print 'Matched #%s: tag name=%s, content=%s' % (i + 1, tag.tag, tag.text)


def main():
    # Finding all <tag> tags
    pprint(etree.HTML('<tag>Tag content</tag>').xpath("//tag"))

    # Finding all stags starts with "t"
    pprint(etree.HTML('<tag>tag1 content</tag><tag2>tag2 conent</tag2><other>other</other>').xpath(
        "//*[starts-with(local-name(), 't')]"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will output:

```
Matched #1: tag name=tag, content=Tag content
Matched #1: tag name=tag, content=tag1 content
Matched #2: tag name=tag2, content=tag2 conent
```

Hope it helps.